# Cross compiling Gnu Radio for Openwrt

Tags: swig, cross-compiling, openwrt, gnuradio

I'm attempting to install Gnu Radio on OpenWRT "Attittude Adjustment" (latest trunk sources). I've cross compiled GR and everything seems to have compiled and linked just fine. However, importing the module in Python results in the following:

```
root@OpenWrt:/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gnuradio/gr# python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Jul 21 2012, 17:36:54) 
[GCC 4.6.3 20120201 (prerelease)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from gnuradio import gr
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gnuradio/gr/__init__.py", line 43, in <module>
    from gnuradio_core import *
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gnuradio/gr/gnuradio_core.py", line 23, in <module>
    from gnuradio_core_runtime import *
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gnuradio/gr/gnuradio_core_runtime.py", line 26, in <module>
    _gnuradio_core_runtime = swig_import_helper()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gnuradio/gr/gnuradio_core_runtime.py", line 22, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_gnuradio_core_runtime', fp, pathname, description)
ImportError: File not found
>>>
```

Note that Python has been invoked in the directory containing the SWIG library. Here is `ldd _gnuradio_core_runtime.so`, running on the **target** system:

```
checking sub-depends for '/usr/lib/libgnuradio-core-3.6.2git.so.0.0.0'
checking sub-depends for '/usr/lib/libgruel-3.6.2git.so.0.0.0'
checking sub-depends for '/usr/lib/libboost_date_time.so.1.49.0'
checking sub-depends for '/usr/lib/libboost_program_options.so.1.49.0'
checking sub-depends for '/usr/lib/libboost_filesystem.so.1.49.0'
checking sub-depends for '/usr/lib/libboost_system.so.1.49.0'
checking sub-depends for '/usr/lib/libboost_thread.so.1.49.0'
checking sub-depends for '/lib/libpthread.so.0'
checking sub-depends for '/usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6'
checking sub-depends for '/lib/libm.so.0'
checking sub-depends for '/lib/libgcc_s.so.1'
checking sub-depends for '/lib/libc.so.0'
checking sub-depends for '/usr/lib/libfftw3f.so.3'
checking sub-depends for 'not found'
checking sub-depends for '/lib/librt.so.0'
checking sub-depends for '/usr/lib/libvolk.so.0.0.0'
checking sub-depends for '/lib/libdl.so.0'
    libgnuradio-core-3.6.2git.so.0.0.0 => /usr/lib/libgnuradio-core-3.6.2git.so.0.0.0 (0x00000000)
    libgruel-3.6.2git.so.0.0.0 => /usr/lib/libgruel-3.6.2git.so.0.0.0 (0x00000000)
    libboost_date_time.so.1.49.0 => /usr/lib/libboost_date_time.so.1.49.0 (0x00000000)
    libboost_program_options.so.1.49.0 => /usr/lib/libboost_program_options.so.1.49.0 (0x00000000)
    libboost_filesystem.so.1.49.0 => /usr/lib/libboost_filesystem.so.1.49.0 (0x00000000)
    libboost_system.so.1.49.0 => /usr/lib/libboost_system.so.1.49.0 (0x00000000)
    libboost_thread.so.1.49.0 => /usr/lib/libboost_thread.so.1.49.0 (0x00000000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/libpthread.so.0 (0x00000000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00000000)
    libm.so.0 => /lib/libm.so.0 (0x00000000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00000000)
    libc.so.0 => /lib/libc.so.0 (0x00000000)
    libfftw3f.so.3 => /usr/lib/libfftw3f.so.3 (0x00000000)
    libfftw3f_threads.so.3 => not found (0x00000000)
    librt.so.0 => /lib/librt.so.0 (0x00000000)
    libvolk.so.0.0.0 => /usr/lib/libvolk.so.0.0.0 (0x00000000)
    libdl.so.0 => /lib/libdl.so.0 (0x00000000)
    ld-uClibc.so.0 => ld-uClibc.so.0 (0x00000000)
```

Here is the output of `file _gnuradio_core_runtime.so` on the **build** system:

```
_gnuradio_core_runtime.so: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, not stripped
```

The target system runs on an Intel Atom. Finally, the last piece of useful information I can think of is that `PYTHONPATH` is set to `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`. I'm at a loss as to what the problem is. I hope the wonderful stack overflow community may help find a solution. Thank you in advance for any pointers!

Comment: `libfftw3f_threads.so.3 => not found (0x00000000)` - I think that's your problem right there. The dynamic linker will refuse to let Python `dlopen()` a library with unsatisfied dependencies.

Comment: This did the trick. Beautiful. I've been grappling with this issue for a while now and had no idea it was because of a missing library. It just appeared to _not be there_. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The target was missing the `libfftw3f_threads.so` library. Since the system call `dlopen()` couldn't resolve the dependencies of `_gnuradio_core_runtime.so`, it told Python the file couldn't be found. I copied the library to the target, did `ldconfig`, and Python loaded the library correctly. (Solution credited to Flexo).