# Python imp module ImportError while load_module

Tags: python, swig

I am using python(2.6.4)-swig(1.3.4) , to access some c++ code that has been compiled into a .so.
swig generates some python code that imports the .so with the help of the imp module.

The find_module succeeds and gets the correct path. But the import_module throws up an ImportError.

```
File "/a/vin31f2/vol/vin31f2v11/cs_ets_03/pradyotd/shadows/testframework/src/MessageRouter/src/swig/MessageFactory.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
_mod = imp.load_module('_MessageFactory', fp, pathname, description)
ImportError: /a/vin31f2/vol/vin31f2v11/cs_ets_03/pradyotd/shadows/testframework/src/MessageRouter/src/swig/_MessageFactory.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory all
```

Please note that the file is infact there `/a/vin31f2/vol/vin31f2v11/cs_ets_03/pradyotd/shadows/testframework/src/MessageRouter/src/swig/_MessageFactory.so`.

Any suggestions as to how I can solve this?

Also , the same thing seems to run in python 2.6.5 on a different machine

Comment: IIRC Python says "No such file or directory" for a library where the its dependencies can't be resolved. Use `ldd` to check they can all be resolved from where you're trying to load it and use `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to add things to the library path if needed.

Comment: Looking at the help for the imp, module it seems there are other methods load_compiled,load_dynamic,load_package, in addition to load_module.

Comment: I actually tried adding my path to the LD_LIBRARY_PATH, that did'nt seem to do it, (and on the machine, where this is not an issue, LD_LIBRARY_PAH was blank)

Comment: Ok, but that doesn't confirm that the linker can resolve all of the depndencies - what does `ldd /a/vin31f2/vol/vin31f2v11/cs_ets_03/pradyotd/shadows/testframework/src/MessageRouter/src/swig/_MessageFactory.so` show? I'd bet it shows not found for at least one. (Basically the same as [Cross compiling Gnu Radio for Openwrt](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11659973) I suspect)

Comment: so on one machine (where it does work, it lists the various libraries linked in). On the problem machine I get the message "not a dynamic executable.
And the load_dynamic was a dead end.

Comment: That would explain the problem you're seeing then - you need to compile and link it correctly for the specific platform you want to run it on.